# Dynamically create object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays which are

```
var data=["a|b|c",
           "d|e|f",
           "g||i",
           "||l"];

var column=[{col:"column1"},
            {col:"column2"},
            {col:"column3"}]//dynamic, can sometimes be up to 10 columns
```

How can i dynamically create an object array based on these two objects?
For example the output should be like this:

```
var newArray =[{column1:"a",column2:"b",column3:"c"},
               {column1:"d",column2:"e",column3:"f"},
               {column1:"g",column2:"",column3:"i"},
               {column1:"",column2:"",column3:"l"}]
```

Comment: is the data a string? please add valid data types to the question.

Comment: Your `data` array is incorrect. Please correct that first

Comment: `[{a|b|c, d|e|f, g||i, ||l}]` is not a valid data structure in perhaps any language

Comment: `{col:"column1",
             col:"column2",
             col:"column3"}` is invalid - object keys must be unique

Comment: @DarrenSweeney updated...

Comment: @AbanaClara updated...

Answer (score 3):

You could map `data` and split the values for new key/value pairs and take a single object for mapping.

```js
var data = ['a|b|c', 'd|e|f', 'g||i', '||l'],
    columns = [{ col: "column1" }, { col: "column2" }, { col: "column3" }],
    result = data.map(s =>
        Object.assign(...s.split('|').map((v, i) => ({ [columns[i].col]: v }))));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<!-- end snippet -->
```

```js
var data = 'a|b|c,d|e|f,g||i,||l'
result = data.split(',').map(function(l, i) {
  var tmp = {}
  l.split('|').forEach(function(t, j) {
    var key = 'column' + (j + 1)
    tmp[key] = t
  })
  return tmp
})
console.log(result);
var data = 'a||'
result = data.split(',').map(function(l, i) {
  var tmp = {}
  l.split('|').forEach(function(t, j) {
    var key = 'column' + (j + 1)
    if (t)
      tmp[key] = t
  })
  return tmp
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if i have something like this? var data='a||'  it will only return the column1.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = 'a|b|c,d|e|f,g||i,||l'
result = data.split(',').map(function(l, i) {
  var tmp = {}
  l.split('|').forEach(function(t, j) {
    var key = 'column' + (j + 1)
    tmp[key] = t
  })
  return tmp
})
console.log(result);
var data = 'a||'
result = data.split(',').map(function(l, i) {
  var tmp = {}
  l.split('|').forEach(function(t, j) {
    var key = 'column' + (j + 1)
    if (t)
      tmp[key] = t
  })
  return tmp
})
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can u cleary say what is the input and what is the output?

Comment: for example if `var data='a||'` the ouput will be `result=["column1":"a","column2":"","column3":""]`

Comment: ["column1":"a","column2":"","column3":""]  SyntaxError format....we cannot make this result in any programming langauage

Comment: my mistake...typo error `[{"column1":"a","column2":"","column3":""}]` i just want it to return all the column even thought the value is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178539/discussion-between-sudhakar-ayyar-and-xion).